# Access Form Saving Capabilities

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

So I had a request by a client and I was wondering if there was anything like this available.

Essentially there is a form called Order.

When this form is loaded the user would type in all necessary information pertaining to this order and submit it to the database for tracking and past due status, payments, check numbers related to order, etc.

He mentions that he runs into several instances where they contract for several shipments of the same product to the same customer and may need the information entered in the first order replicated for 10 different orders.

Is there some way I can save and copy the contents they enter into the form so that it can be reloaded when they want to enter it again?

Of course the date information would need to be editable before they submit again.

But how could I implement that functionality? Is VB capable of "listening" to the forms contents and copy paste it back into the same fields/values accordingly?

I'm not too familiar with VB, so any help in this arena would be greatly appreciated.

Attached is the picture of the form he uses to input records. I think the approach for me would be to add a couple buttons on the side under the Add New Order button.

Perhaps the first one can grab the record data, and the second can perhaps map the values back
[image: Form]

Comment: Are you using VB.net front end to an Access database (seems odd) or VBA with Access database? Tags seem to not make sense.

Comment: Do you want to clone an existing record and allow the user to specify an order date for that cloned record?

Comment: @KevenDenen No. This is an Access Form. Some buttons are using VB. Sorry for confusion feel free to edit.

Comment: @HansUp I think so. Essentially data flow would be input data into fields. save before or after entered into Db. Functional button to clone record they can click once perhaps, and then another to paste it back into the form for editing dates n such....does this make sense?

Comment: I think so.  So then after the user chooses a combination of customer and product, you show her a list of matching orders, allow her to choose one, and copy information (other than date) from the selected order to a new order record.  She can input the date in the new record.  Does that make sense?

Comment: hmmm..interesting approach. a list of matching orders? or the last order? Which would be simpler? Date is an auto-generated field using today's date. but yes, the idea is there.

Comment: You're still not answering the first comment: Are you using VBA only, or are you using VB.net ? In other words: are you only using Access tools (including the VBA editor) or are you using other tools (like Visual Studio)?

Comment: Why is there still a question? Look at the tags.

Comment: @HansUp did you have an answer for this?

Comment: No, I was exploring a strategy to attack this thing.  But I think the scope is too large for a suitable Stack Overflow answer.  Can you narrow this down?  Maybe start by giving the user a method to select an existing customer and product?

Comment: If I post a screenshot of the form will that help?

Comment: I doubt a screenshot would narrow the scope of this thing sufficiently.  But you can try.  Maybe I'm off base.

Comment: Well I appreciate your thoughts man. I hope this helps.

Comment: OK, to the point. Let's assume you fill the form *and* save the data to the database. When the user wants to fill the form again, "somehow" the application must know what data should be retrieved from the database to fill the form. How would you select that data? With VBA it is possible to fill the controls with values, but they must be stored somewhere. Would those "new default values" should be the last values entered and saved by the user?

Comment: hmm...great question @Barranka I think it would be the last created record. I could write a query to do this. TOP 1 order by CP_Ref Desc type deal, but how does VB refill the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I've understood what you want, and **YES**, there's a way to pull that out.

In your comment you said you want to retreive the last created record, and you even post the query you could use to retreive it. So let's use that query to pull your values and put them in your form.

Let's say you have a command button [cmd_fill_default]. In its `onClick` event you should write something like this:

```
sub cmd_fill_default_onClick()
    dim db as DAO.Database, rs as DAO.RecordSet
    dim strSQL as String

    Set db = currentdb() ' Connect to your current database
    ' Retrieve the last record
    strSQL = "select top 1 a.* from your_table as a order by [CP_Ref] desc"
    set rs = db.openRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    ' Move to the first (and only) row in the record set
    rs.moveFirst

    ' Now, you must fill each control (text box, combo box, check box, etcetera)
    ' with the retrieved values.
    ' I don't know how your controls are called, but it would be something 
    ' like this:
    txt_something.value = rs![something]
    txt_another_thing.value = rs![another_thing]
    ' and so on

    ' Once you're done, remember to close everything
    rs.close
    db.close
end sub
```

Now your controls will be filled with data, and they will be editable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Great answer. You answer the question, you surrender some useful code, and you have excellent comments. I appreciate it. Let me get some time to work this out and I will select your answer!

Comment: @Hituptony Happy to help. Be sure to check out the documentation for DAO to see the things you can do with it.

Comment: so this would be for example. CP_Ref.ControlSource = rs!CP_Ref ?

Comment: No. If you do that, you'll not be able to edit the value. It should be CP_Ref.Text (assuming it's a text box)

Comment: and for this DueDate.Text = rs!DueDate it says invalid use of null

Comment: Also, when I change to text it says I can't call the method unless the control is in focus, not sure what that means...

Comment: Try then .value... And you must check if the value in rs.field is not null (if it is, skip it)

Comment: is there any way you can check out my latest question and perhaps help me out again? I really appreciate it...